# How can I allow the user to choose what place to put the application? (if in the internal or external storage)

Tags: android

My application stays always in the internal memory of the device and if the user try move it to the Sd card it's not possible the button "Move to the sd card" gets disable, I wanna know how can I give to the user the power to choose how place put my application;

Comment: what you said doesn't allow the user to choose where the install the application

Comment: The user will never will be prompted where to install the application. If installLocation set to auto, the system choose as for the other two possibilities. But if this is set, the user later can install to external/internal memory. If the installLocation not set, it will only allow internal memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your manifest file inside

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xy.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" >
```

If you set it auto, the system choose where to install and the user can move to external/internal memory if available (for example a widget not available). Available options: `"auto"`, `"internalOnly"`, `"preferExternal"`.
For more informations: [Android Developer App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)